# input exception error in Java

Tags: java

I keep getting an exception error. This is a simple code. Why am I getting an exception error?

```
class ThirdProgram
{
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  System.out.println("Hello out there.");
  System.out.println("I will add two numbers for you.");
  System.out.println("Enter two whole numbers on a line.");

  int n1, n2;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
  n2 = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("The sum of those two numbers is");
  System.out.println(n1 + n2);
 }
}
```

Comment: What *exception* (*error*) do you get?

Comment: I know that the import java.util.Scanner; needs to be added.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at ThirdProgram.main(Main.java:11)

Comment: @user2569708 I tested your code, it works perfectly

Comment: Please post your actual code

Comment: You must have entered less than 2 numbers.

Comment: @rgettman No. Scanner keeps asking for input unless you enter all inputs it wants. If your code asks for 2 numbers, Scanner will loop unless the two numbers are entered.

Comment: Could it be the online complier? using Ideone.com. My teacher did mention that there is trick to this one. I will run through my linux box. Thank you.

Comment: Enter a number at a time.  So say you want to add 5 and 7, type 5 then hit enter.  Then type 7, then hit enter.

Comment: It is not asking for numbers at all through this compiler

Comment: @BackSlash You could still get an InputMismatchException if you type something that is not an integer

Comment: @BackSlash Sure, but when I ended the stream prematurely, by hitting Ctrl-D, I can reproduce the `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: using this website(Ideone.com) there is a link under the code, to enter the inputs before running the code. The values are separated by spaces. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

When you use:

http://ideone.com/

Do the following:

**Step 1**

Make sure you select Java on the left.

**Step 2**

Enter this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class ThirdProgram
{
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  System.out.println("Hello out there.");
  System.out.println("I will add two numbers for you.");
  System.out.println("Enter two whole numbers on a line.");

  int n1, n2;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
  n2 = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("The sum of those two numbers is");
  System.out.println(n1 + n2);
 }
}
```

**Step 3**

Before you hit the SUBMIT button, click `click here to enter input (stdin) or additional note`.  Once you click it, two boxes will appear.  In the first box ( `enter your input (stdin)` ), enter:

```
5

7
```

Make sure you press enter after the 7.

**Step 4**

Then hit SUBMIT.  The results will load up for you at the bottom.

**NOTE:**

You should download and use an IDE instead (like JGrasp or Eclipse).  Most IDEs come with compilers and allow you to enter the input in after you run the program from some console.